# How can scientists measure the electron affinity and the ionization energy of an element?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, elements

I am pretty curious about the method that the scientists use to measure the electron affinity and the ionization energy of an element. If someone knows about it, please tell me.

Comment: Did you consider consulting a reference like a textbook, or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity or https://www.britannica.com/science/ionization-energy?